# Android ListView not show scrollbar when fastscroll

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, fastscroll

When I scroll the list, fastscroll thumb is showed but the scrollbar thumb and track not showed.

Here is my XML code:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/bg_scroll"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_bar"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_line"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`/>
```

My fastscroll thumb drawable is setted in `styles.xml` **AppTheme**.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data you passed to list view because fast scroll is only displayed when you have more list items to scroll.

Make sure you have these lines in recycler view tag

```
app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable">
```

Comment: My fastscroll is displayed, but the scrollbar track and thumb is not.

Comment: I updated the answer. Check/add that in your code and Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I use listview.When my list size is greater than or equal to 4 pages, fast scroll works; normal scrollbar thumb, track (not the track of fastscroll) don't work. I want normal scrollbar thumb, track  always show and fastscroll enable when scrolling the list.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have set `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` you need to set the fastScroll properties like `android:fastScrollTrackDrawable="@drawable/"`and `'android:fastScrollThumbDrawable="@drawable/"`. And also consider what @Gouse Mohiddin has said. You need to have enough rows inside to make it scrollable.

Comment: The fastscroll is working properly but scrollbar not working.